# Audit.NET obtain database credentials dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hashicorp-vault, audit.net

We are using [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) library in our Asp.Net Core project to log user actions. Recently we have decided to use [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) to securely store and obtain secrets including **database credentials**. Vault engine [automatically rotates database credentials](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/database-creds-rotation?in=vault/secrets-management) on the configured period of time, so static credentials are not an option anymore.

Thus, we had to implement a service which will serve the current connection string (we are using **PostgreSql**) to the required services. In case of the DB context it is possible to get the connection string at runtime using the following code in **Startup.cs**:

```
 services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
        {
            var databaseCredentialsProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionStringProvider>();
            var connectionString = databaseCredentialsProvider.GetConnectionString();
            options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
        });
```

However, regarding the Audit.NET configuration, it seems that it can only set static credentials. We are using the following code in **Startup.cs** to configure the Audit.NET.

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
            .UsePostgreSql(config => config
                    .ConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString(""))
                    .Schema("")
                    .TableName("")
                    .IdColumnName("")
                    .DataColumn("", DataType.JSONB)
                    .LastUpdatedColumnName("");
            );
```

I've looked through the source code of **UsePostgreSql** - it sets the credentials once so it is not an option to use this extension method.

Is there any way to configure Audit.NET to obtain database credentials dynamically? Should I implement custom **UsePostgreSql** provider then?

Comment: I think it could help to provide a `ConnectionStringBuilder` as a `Func<string>`, just like the [SqlProvider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/a476cacfa33aef73e54f85240af17ef3fc0b03a6/src/Audit.NET.SqlServer/Providers/SqlDataProvider.cs#L44) does. So the connection string is resolved each time an event is about to be saved. Could you [open an issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose) on the github project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest version you can now setup the configuration values as Functions, so the values will be retrieved when the audit events are created. For example:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UsePostgreSql(config => config
        .ConnectionString(_ => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionStringProvider>().GetConnectionString())
        .Schema("")
        .TableName("")
        .IdColumnName("")
        .DataColumn("", DataType.JSONB)
        .LastUpdatedColumnName("");
    );
```

Comment: Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup should be in ConfigureServices in the Startup then? currently I have Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup, Audit.Core.Configuration.AddCustomAction and Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup in Configure

Comment: If you need something from the DI mechanism you should put it on the `Configure` method, otherwise could be on either place.